# Something Wrong with QuickSort algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, java.util.scanner, quicksort

Quick Sort Java Implementation-
I have made a program to implement QuickSort algorithm, but it is not showing the sorted sequence properly, It is also showing array out of bound Index exception. can someone tell what is wrong with code or logic?

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSort{
    int num,arrayQS[],i;

    public void quicksort(int ar[],int start,int end){
        if(start<end){
            int pindex=partition(ar,start,end);
            System.out.println(pindex);
            quicksort(ar,start,pindex-1);
            quicksort(ar,pindex+1,end);
        }
    }
    public int partition(int pAR[],int start, int end){ //partition function

        int key;
        int swapper;
        int pivot=pAR[end];
        int pIndex=start;
        for(i=0;i<end;i++){
            if(pAR[i]<=pivot){
                //swapiing
                key=pAR[pIndex];
                pAR[pIndex]=pAR[i];
                pAR[i]=key;
                pIndex++;
            }
        }
        //swap
        swapper=pAR[pIndex];
        pAR[pIndex]=pAR[end];
        pAR[end]=swapper;
        return pIndex;
    }
    public void arrayInputFn(){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number you want to insert in an array");
        num=in.nextInt();
        arrayQS=new int[num];
        System.out.println("enter the elements in an array: ");
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
            arrayQS[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        quicksort(arrayQS,0,arrayQS.length-1);

        for(i=0;i<arrayQS.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arrayQS[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        QuickSort qs=new QuickSort();
        qs.arrayInputFn();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(i=0;i<end;i++){` the beginning index should be `start`, not `0`. You are passing the entire array to the method but you only sort part of it at once (other than the first call), as specified by `start` and `end`.

You should also extract swap method to make the code much neater.

```
public int partition(int pAR[], int start, int end) {
    int pivot = pAR[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (pAR[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(pAR, i, pIndex);
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(pAR, pIndex, end);
    return pIndex;
}

public void swap(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    int temp = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = temp;
}
```